# Can I change the root directory of the session storage?

Tags: java, swing, jsr296

Currently the session storage saves all session files in a system dependand folder suited for session state files.

But in one of my applications I want the session files be saved in a special directory.

Can I change the root directory of the session storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's easy. From the ApplicationContext:

```
ApplicationContext.getLocalStorage().setDirectory(new File("/mydirectory"));
```

I often used it during GUI tests so that I could pre-setup the geometry required by my tests (rather than forcing move and resize at every test launch).